# Custom animation when item removed in recycleview

Tags: android, animation, expandablerecyclerview

I'm trying to fade out items when it's removed then collapse recycleview. But it doesn't work.
Please help me

```
for(Object appData : mInvisibleEntries){
       mVisibleEntries.remove(appData);
}

for(View view:viewHoldersList){
       Animation a = new AlphaAnimation(1.00f, 0.00f);
       a.setDuration(2000);
       view.startAnimation(a);
}
notifyItemRangeRemoved(MAX_VISIBLE_APPS_COUNT + 1, mInvisibleEntries.size());
collapseRv();

private void collapseRv(){
    final int initialHeight = mRecyclerView.getMeasuredHeight();
    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(initialHeight,HEIGHT_VIEW_APPDATA*3+HEIGHT_SECTION_FOOTER);
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            mRecyclerView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            mRecyclerView.requestLayout();
        }
    });
    valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    valueAnimator.setDuration(2000);
    valueAnimator.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it simlpe, You can use library like https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators

Comment: As i see, using SimpleItemAnimator quite complicated